# Can I solve system of differential equation in a matrix form?

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to solve simple system of differential equations:

x'[t] == 6x[t] - 6y[t], y'[t] == x[t]-2y[t];

but I want to avoid formulas like DSolve[{x'[t] == 6x[t] - 4y[t], y'[t] == x[t]-2y[t]}, {x,y},t] as I want to put equation in a matrix form.
My idea was something like that (based od Wolfram's documentation):

```
X[t_] = {{x[t]},{y[t]}};

A={{6,-4},{1,-2}};

eqs=D[X[t],t] == A.X[t];

Dsolve[eqs,{x,y},t]
```

...and I got the error message: There should be no lists on either side of the equations. Any ideas where is the problem? Thanks in advantage!
Cheers,

Comment: You might be interested in `MatrixExp[]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[x, y, t]
X0[t_] := {x[t], y[t]};
A0 = {{6, -4}, {1, -2}};
eqs = Thread[D[X0[t], t] == A0.X0[t]]
DSolve[eqs, X0[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I am sure this question has been asked before and it is duplicate.